# How can I use PHP to validate form input in an HTML file?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm making a dropdown menu item to sign in, but I have no idea how to validate the form input. I do have a page to sign up, which redirects to a PHP file with the following code:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->RegisterUser())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("thank-you.html");
   }
}

?>
```

This code then redirects to another html file. Eventually you get redirected to a login.php file with the following code:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("../index.html");
   }
}

?>
```

It all works fine, but my problem with it is that it's now only possible to login via separate pages. I want to be able to login via a dropdown, but I can't use the same PHP code as above, since the dropdown is inside an html file. How do I:

- Use PHP to validate the form input
- Redirect users to the page they were visiting when they clicked the dropdown item

Edit: this is the form I use in my login.php file:

```
<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<h2 class="titel2">Log in</h2>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>


<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>

    <input class="veld" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>

    <input class="veld" placeholder="Wachtwoord" type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error centreren'></span>

    <div class="centreren"></div><a class="anormaal" href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Wachtwoord vergeten?</a></div>

    <input class="knop2" type='submit' name='Submit' value='Log in' />

</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about validation, here is example, may you help.

```
if(empty($_POST['something']) === TRUE)
{
   $error[]= 'Your field is empty';
}
```

Use this for redirection:

```
header('Location: 'yourphpscript.php');
exit;
```